# Using TimeBasedRollingPolicy of Spring

Tags: java, spring-mvc, logging

Here is logback.xml code that I am using:

```
<configuration>
<property resource="C:\Code\pin-ws\pin-war\src\main\resources\META-INF\config\app.properties" scope="context" />
    <appender name="FILE"
        class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
        <file>${log.location}\pin-app.log</file>
        <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
            <FileNamePattern>${log.location}\pin-app.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.log
            </FileNamePattern>
        </rollingPolicy>
        <encoder>
            <pattern>%date %level [%thread] %X{username} [%file:%line] %msg%n
            </pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>
    <root level="DEBUG">
        <appender-ref ref="FILE" />
    </root>
    </configuration>
```

1. I am trying to fetch the value of the log location from my app.properties. But its not working. Can someone please suggest what property tag should I be using instead?
2. When I hard-code the log location inside the logback.xml itself, I can see the logs getting printed in my log file.
   But even in this case, only pin-app.log is getting appended with values but pin-app.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.log is not getting created.
   Am I doing something wrong in using TimeBasedRollingPolicy?
3. Just curious, is it possible for us to print the value (like ${log.location} in this example) in the console from the xml file?

I am using simple Spring 4 MVC, not SpringBoot and below are the versions of slf4j and logback that I am using:

```
<version.slf4j>1.6.4</version.slf4j>
<version.logback>1.0.1</version.logback>
<java-version>1.8</java-version>
```

Comment: For the property resource, "app.properties" should do it instead of the complete path (into the war-file as it seems) which might be wrong/change over time.

Comment: I think path for app.properties is required to be provided, be it absolute or relative. I tried giving absolute path in order to fetch log.location value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<property>
```

has options "**file**" and "**resource**".

**Examples**:

```
<property resource="logging.properties"/> <!-- Path relavtive to classpath. E.g. file in src/main/resources or within .jar when built -->
```

or

```
<property file="logging.properties"/> <!-- File in root folder of project or folder where your .jar is located -->
```

For the case you described (with the fully qualified path) it works with the "**file**"-option.

For the 3. question: Yes, the [documentation](https://logback.qos.ch/manual/configuration.html#variableSubstitution) states *"Variable substitution can occur at any point in a configuration file where a value can be specified."*

**Example**:

Property file:

```
randomProperty=Hello
```

Logback.xml:

```
<pattern>${randomProperty} %date %level [%thread] %X{username} [%file:%line] %msg%n</pattern>
```

**Additional hint:**

```
<configuration debug="true">
```

will show you a little bit more about actual problems when initializing the logging.